# Diagonal arrows/vectors not working

Tags: arrows, vector

For some reason I can't get diagonal arrows/vectors to work. Only the arrowhead shows up - the line is missing. For example, in the following, the first vector is fine (horizontal) but the second just gives a floating arrowhead.

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{picture}(60, 40)
  \put(30, 20){\vector(1, 0){30}}
  \put(30, 20){\vector(4, 1){20}}
\end{picture}
```

I've tried using `\thicklines`, `\thinlines`, doesn't make a difference.

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: As I said to your [crosspost on LaTeX-Communtity.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=18469), the code snippet is working and shows lines. Perhaps provide a complete example which show the undesired behavior.

Comment: Hi Mark, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I've removed the thanks. It's just the style here. Thanks is best expressed in the up voting of answers that are helpful.

Comment: If you are just starting out with drawing pictures, I would highly recommend looking at `tikz`. For example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, -latex]
 \draw[red] (0,0) -- (4,0);
 \draw[blue] (0,0) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

You could load the [`pict2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pict2e) package. It extends the existing LaTeX `picture` environment using driver files and solves the issue with limited slope values for lines and vectors.